# overding some properties of css class for a div

Tags: html, css

I have a div to which i appy a css class.Now in css class heigh is decalred as x px but i want my div  to be of y px.How can i overide hight paramater of css without changing css.

Comment: ur question is vague, are u a beginner in CSS? or ur trying to override style of content u cannot control? can u use javascript?

Comment: Yeah, if you're going to drop a bombshell like "change style without using CSS" you should say why!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div style="height: 80px"></div>
```

The browser assigns the styles with the highest *specificity* to the elements. [As you can read here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity) 'style' has the highest specificity.

You can override specificity by using [the !important declaration](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/using-important-css/).

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to override the value of a CSS attribute defined in a class.

This is really a huge topic, though -- so if you really want to understand this stuff, [start here](http://htmldog.com/guides/cssadvanced/specificity/) with a tutorial on CSS Specificity.

Answer (score 0):

use inline css with **!important** tag

```
<div class="yourclass" style="height:ypx!important">
```

Comment: you are missing ending double quotes !!! Also make sure you provide style after you applied css class <span class="" style="height:ypx!important" />

Comment: inline style by default overrides class style, no need for important keyword

Comment: @ayyash u r right,if `important` tag is written in class , so its better to use important in inline css

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the CSS to overwrite it - either use the cascade to give it a new value, or add an inline `style` attribute which has precedence over external styles declarations (watch for `!important`).

Answer (score 0):

CSS declarations *cascade*. Meaning you can attach additional rules to other CSS classes and assign both to an element:

```
<style type="text/css">
.style1 {
  color: red;
  height: 100px;
}
.style1.style2 {
  height: 200px;
}
</style>

<!-- This DIV will have a height of 200px and red foreground color -->
<div class="style1 style2"></div>
```